# ArrayList only stores one object

Tags: java, arraylist

My Arraylist Only stores one object in it. Every time a new object is entered, it overwrites the current one.

Calling method:

```
    public void saveBookingInfo(View view) {

    EditText applicantNameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.applicantNameTextField);
    EditText itemToBurnText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemToBurnTextField);

    String appName = applicantNameText.getText().toString();
    String appItemToBurn = itemToBurnText.getText().toString();

    if (appItemToBurn.isEmpty() || appName.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(BookingScreen.this, "Please fill in all fields.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        sendApplication.storeApplication(appName, appItemToBurn);
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

ArrayList method:

```
  public void storeApplication(String name, String item){
    ArrayList<Application> peopleAttending = new ArrayList<>(10);
    peopleAttending.add(new Application(name, item));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're declaring the `List<Application>` as local parameter to the method. Move it as a field in the class instead.

```
private List<Application> peopleAttending = new ArrayList<>();

public void storeApplication(String name, String item) {
    peopleAttending.add(new Application(name, item));
}
```

Comment: I've ran into a problem with that. because the object 'Send Application' is of type GAClass, it clears the arraylist as the arraylist would be contained within the object, and when that method gets destroyed, the arraylist does too :/

Comment: Well, we don't have a magic crystal ball to see all your code that lies within your computer only. We cannot imagine the scope of the list unless you explain your real problem. AFAIK this solves the problem stated in your question. If you need this list to live longer, then you should define it in a class whose object reference lives long enough and pass it as parameter to instances of classes that have less lifespan like this one.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a `new` ArrayList every time you call the method. You should create the `ArrayList` exactly once and pass a reference to the method, or make the reference an instance variable.

Comment: Could you give me a written example please. I learn better from seeing demonstrations.:)

Answer (score 0):

you can try changing the constructor of the class for object sendApplication

```
class SendApplication{
    List<Application> peopleAttending = null;
    public SendApplication(){
        List<Application> peopleAttending = new ArrayList<Application>();
    }
    public void storeApplication(String name, String item) {
        peopleAttending.add(new Application(name, item));
    } //...... other methods follow
}
```